# Bootstrap Hypothesis Testing Sample Size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, sample-size, ab-test

I want to use bootstrap to test a hypothesis. I can't figure out how to find out the minimum possible sizes of control and experiment groups. Can you suggest what methods exist for this?

Comment: Did you already collect the data? Are you asking how many samples per bootstrap sample? Or are you trying to determine what the minimum sample size should be to perform a test with pre-specified parameters?

Comment: I'm struggling with the experiment design, I didn't collect the data yet. I'm trying to determine the minimum experiment sample size, not bootstrap samples.